# Change settings to scan a printer with openvas

Tags: vulnerability-scanners, printers, openvas

I have Openvas 5.1.1 (gui: Greenbone Security Assistant Version 7.0.2).

It misidentifies my linux server as a printer. Scan result includes

```
Solution

If you want to scan the remote host, uncheck the 'Exclude printers from scan' option within the 'Global variable settings' and re-scan it.
```

Using the web UI, I can see the settings:

[image]

but I can't find out **how to change it**. The configuration files doesn't include any such option:

```
root@kali:~# find / -name openvas*conf
/etc/openvas/openvasmd_log.conf
/etc/openvas/openvassd.conf
root@kali:~#
root@kali:~# cat /etc/openvas/openvassd.conf
kb_location=/var/run/redis/redis.sock
```

Actually the documentation doesn't include that option for the `openvassd.conf` file, at all: http://www.openvas.org/compendium/advanced-configuration-server.html

Any ideas?

Comment: You can include a lot of the config options in the openvassd.conf file but I don't believe you can set the printer option. You might want to post this on a openvas forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to me that you're trying to edit a pre-made and static configuration.
You're correct that you're not supposed to change it in the .conf file.
What I'd recommend doing is:

1 Cloning the scan you want (In this case "Full and Very Deep Ultimate") by clicking the sheep icon next to it in the "Scan Configs" page.

2 Going back to the "Scan Configs" page, from the page it will take you too and editing it by clicking the wrench button.

3 Scroll to the bottom and click on the folder icon next to "Network Vulnerability Test Preferences".

4 Scroll down until you reach "Global variable settings Exclude printers from scan", and click on the wrench icon to edit.

5 Look for "Exclude printers from scan", and disable it.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: As this answer is correct it should be noted that the "Exclude printers from scan" should be changed only if this is actually a printer and you're sure that it can handle the scan (there are quite a lot printers out there with a fragile network stack.

Additionally if a linux server got identified as a printer please report such plugin issues directly to http://lists.wald.intevation.org/cgi-bin/mailman/listinfo/openvas-plugins